# python how to get re to ignore parentheses in raw text

Tags: python, regex

I'm using re.search to search a lot of strings and some of them contain unbalanced parentheses. How do I tell it to ignore these for re purposes? I just want it to treat it as a raw string. However, these strings are in a list so in the re expression, I can't just put an r' in front of it:

```
for a in some_list:
    for b in some_other_list:
        if re.search(a[0],b[0], re.I):
            do stuff....
```

In that example a[0] contains a string and I want it to treat every "(" or ")" character as just that, and not re code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance escaping and regex-compiling is best done outside of your inner loop:

```
for a in some_list:
    pat = re.compile(re.escape(a[0]), re.I)
    for b in some_other_list:
        if pat.search(b[0]):
            do stuff....
```

Comment: great! Will re.escape(string) also escape characters that might cause problems with mysql queries?

Comment: `re` module caches patterns with default `re._MAXCACHE` of about 100 IIRC, so `re.compile` is rarely needed.

Comment: Precompiling REs in such cases avoids to have the system do the lookup in the cache then ;-)

Comment: Marc, re.escape() only escapes the characters significant for regular expressions.  SQL injection problems are a whole 'nother field of joy.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want to use `re.escape` on the string.

> `re.escape(string)`
>
> Return string with all non-alphanumerics
> backslashed; this is useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal
> string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it.

([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape))